# Reference current model in mongoose validator plugin

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose validator called when a User record is saved, to ensure the email is unique. This "unique" check is actually handled by a mongoose validator plugin.

When `User.save` is called, it works fine - but when `User.findOneAndUpdate` is called with `{ runValidators: true }`, the validator fails because `this` is undefined:

```
function (value, respond) {
    var model = this.model(this.constructor.modelName);
}
```

I'm guessing that mongoose invokes the validator differently - in such a way that `this` changes.

Is there a better/safer way to determine/reference the current model? I'm not seeing any consistent properties on `this` that would work.

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: Sort of, I reported the issue and Mongoose added an optional context for updates: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3430